# Excel Right function

Tags: excel

I have a excel sheet with cell value 0.010, 0.020 etc., I want to get the values 3 digits after the decimal ie., "010" "020" etc., If I use the Right function Right(cell,3) it returns me ".01" ".02". The reason is the Right function ignores the "0" at the end of decimal point. Is there any other function that accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably first need to convert the numeric value to a string:

```
=RIGHT(TEXT(CELL,"0.000"),3)
```

Comment: Yelton... I was about to post this solution and you got it... thanks.